# Assigning multiple variables in one line

Tags: python

I am trying to make the Fibonacci sequence I don't get why this:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    f1 = 0
    f2 = 1
    i = 1

    while i < n:
        print(f2)
        f1 = f2
        f2 = f1 + f2

        i += 1
    return f3
```

returns 1, 2, 4, 8, while this:

```
def fibonacci(n):

    f1 = 0
    f2 = 1
    i = 1

    while i < n:
        print(f2)
        f1, f2 = f2, f1 + f2
        i += 1
    return f3
```

returns the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: When you assign variables in one line, they're all assign at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried going through it line by line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the latter example, the right hand side is evaluated *first*:

```
f1, f2 = f2, f1 + f2
```

So the value of `f1` used in the calculation of `f2` is the *"old"* value.

In your code, when you do:

```
f1 = f2
f2 = f1 + f2
```

the value of `f1` has already changed when you go to evaluate the new value for `f2`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the value of `f1` from the previous iteration is discarded before `f2` is updated.

```
f1, f2 = f2, f1 + f2
```

can be seen as shorthand for

```
tmp = f1
f1 = f2
f2 = tmp + f2
```

if that helps it make more sense. The latter is what you'd have to do in many other languages to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

The variables f1 and f2 **simultaneously** get the new values f2 and f1 + f2, the expression

f1, f2 = f2, f1 + f2.

Demonstrating that the expressions on the right-hand side are all evaluated first **before any of the assignments take place**. f1 + f2 use the f1 old value we don't use the f1 new value. The right-hand side expressions are evaluated from the left to the right.